# How can I retrieve data for an Entity based on a column from another entity using spring data JPA?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a goal table, a match table, and a competition table.
Each goal has a matchId and each match has a competitionId so If I want to retrieve all goals from a competition I do this:

```
select * from mydb.goal g
JOIN mydb.matches m
ON g.goal_match = m.matchid
JOIN mydb.competitions c
ON m.competition = c.competitionid
WHERE c.competitionid = 219;
```

I have a Spring data JPA project, I have my 3 entities This is Goal:

```
@Entity
public class Goal {

@Id
private long idgoal;
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "goalMatch")
private Match goalMatch;

public long getIdgoal() {
    return idgoal;
}

public void setIdgoal(long idgoal) {
    this.idgoal = idgoal;
}

public Match getGoalMatch() {
    return goalMatch;
}

public void setGoalMatch(Match goalMatch) {
    this.goalMatch = goalMatch;
}

}
```

This is Match

```
@Entity(name = "matches")
public class Match {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long idmatch;
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "competition")
private Competition competition;

public long getIdmatch() {
    return idmatch;
}

public void setIdmatch(long idmatch) {
    this.idmatch = idmatch;
}

public Competition getCompetition() {
    return competition;
}

public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
    this.competition = competition;
}

}
```

And Competition:

```
@Entity(name = "competitions")
public class Competition {

@Id
private Long idcompetitions;

public Long getIdcompetitions() {
    return idcompetitions;
}
public void setIdcompetitions(Long idcompetitions) {
    this.idcompetitions = idcompetitions;
}
}
```

Then I have my goal repository where I'm trying to find a way to retrieve all goals from a competition but I can't find a way to do it except with a long @Query.

**Is there a straight forward way for Spring Data JPA to do that?** 
Or should I just use a custom @Query?

Comment: `@Query("select g from Goal g where g.goalMatch.competition.id = :competitionId")`. This is pretty basic stuff. You need to read the Hibernate manual, and in particular the chapter about JPQL / HQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JB Nizet was pretty close:

The correct Query is:

```
@Query("select g from Goal g where g.goalMatch.competition.idcompetitions = :competitionId")
```